# Removing Space row(i dont know, whether its row or not) in pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I've been working on a dataframe and in a result I got this:

```
Probability ID
    ID      
    4   0.013925    4
    6   0.053906    6
    10  0.001792    10
```

It was created by this line:

```
NewXGB['Probability'] = group.Predictions.sum()/group.size()
```

Working on pandas indexes is hard for me, so I am seeking your help and I can't the make this null row disappear! 
I'm OK with two variants:

1.

```
Probability ID      
    1   0.013925    4
    2   0.053906    6
    3   0.001792    10
```

2.

```
Probability         
    4   0.013925    
    6   0.053906
    10  0.001792
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use [reset_index()](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.reset_index.html) method:

```
In [42]: df
Out[42]:
    Probability  ID
ID
4      0.013925   4
6      0.053906   6
10     0.001792  10

In [43]: df = df.reset_index(drop=True)

In [44]: df
Out[44]:
   Probability  ID
0     0.013925   4
1     0.053906   6
2     0.001792  10
```

if you just want to remove the index name:

```
In [35]: df = df.rename_axis(None)

In [36]: df
Out[36]:
    Probability  ID
4      0.013925   4
6      0.053906   6
10     0.001792  10

In [37]: df.index.name

In [38]: df.index
Out[38]: Int64Index([4, 6, 10], dtype='int64')
```